# Gitlab-CE reconfigure time out on step "migrate gitlab-rails database"

Tags: gitlab

I try to update gitlab from version 9.5.10 to latest 10. I do 3 steps:

1. touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-migrations ( I don't need backup )
2. yum -y install gitlab-ce-10.8.7-ce.0.el7.x86_64
3. gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Gitlab crashes with an error after one hour:

## ...

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
--------------------------------
Command timed out after 3600s:
Command exceeded allowed execution time, process terminated
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20180907-58298-lhgdju" ----
STDOUT: == 20141126120926 AddMergeRequestRebaseEnabledToProjects: migrating ===========
-- transaction_open?()
   -> 0.0000s

...

     63:   end
     64:   not_if "(test -f #{db_migrate_status_file}) && (cat #{db_migrate_status_file} | grep -Fx 0)"
     65:   only_if { node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['auto_migrate'] }
     66: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb:49:in `from_file'

    bash("migrate gitlab-rails database") do
      action [:run]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      command nil
      backup 5
      returns 0
      user nil
      interpreter "bash"
      declared_type :bash
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "database_migrations"
      code "    set -e\n    log_file=\"/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).log\"\n    umask 077\n    /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}\n    STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}\n    echo $STATUS > /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-141d998df14e11465b19f94d3c4ccfa1-eb600b0\n    exit $STATUS\n"
      domain nil
      not_if "(test -f /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-141d998df14e11465b19f94d3c4ccfa1-eb600b0) && (cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-141d998df14e11465b19f94d3c4ccfa1-eb600b0 | grep -Fx 0)"
      only_if { #code block }
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.6.4
    platform=centos
    platform_version=7.4.1708
    ruby=ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client

Recipe: gitlab::unicorn
  * service[unicorn] action restart
    ESC[32m- restart service service[unicorn]
Recipe: gitlab::sidekiq
  * service[sidekiq] action restart
    ESC[32m- restart service service[sidekiq]
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action run
    ESC[32m- execute /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 25 resources updated in 01 hours 01 minutes 28 seconds
```

I found [workaround](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36615) but I don't want to risk changing the update procedure. GitLab is used in the production and use of more than 1000 people (An update check is performed on the copy of the database).

Does anyone know how to increase the timeout?

Comment: 3600 seconds is the default timeout for `Mixlib::ShellOut`, so if there is no way to cleanly override it, you could edit `/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/provider/execute.rb` line 47.

Comment: Thank you so much! For the first time the update was completed without errors :" Running handlers complete. Chef Client finished, 58/411 resources updated in 04 hours 53 minutes 08 seconds"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turning this into an answer so other people might be able to use this:

Unless someone knows of a way to override the default timeout for `Mixlib::ShellOut` in this case, it is possible to override that default of `3600` in `opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.6.4/lib/chef/provider/execute.rb` line 44-48, which currently read:

```
def timeout
  # original implementation did not specify a timeout, but ShellOut
  # *always* times out. So, set a very long default timeout
  new_resource.timeout || 3600
end
```

Increasing the `3600` there should help.

Answer (score 0):

That should no longer be any issue with [GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#remove-hardcoded-time-limit-for-migrations-to-complete) (December 2023):

> ### Remove hardcoded time limit for migrations to complete
>
> GitLab groups and project migrations done by direct transfer can become stuck for various reasons.
>
> In the past, to avoid leaving these migrations in an incomplete state indefinitely, GitLab periodically executed a worker to identify migrations that hadn’t completed within 8 hours. GitLab marked these migrations as timed out.
>
> For large organizations, the migration process can take longer than 8 hours, so this amount of time was not always sufficient to properly determine if a migration was stuck.
> As a result, this worker might have incorrectly marked a migration as stuck.
>
> In this milestone, instead of using an 8 hour time limit, GitLab now only marks the migration as stuck if the child workers stop working for 24 hours.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#limits) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/429867).